# Finding Wordpress 302 Redirects

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I'm getting an HTTP Code 302 redirect for some "pages" in WordPress, and have no idea where WordPress is deciding to redirect them.

I have a "login" page set up in WordPress, with a file "page-login.php" in the theme directory. That file includes a line at the top that says:

```
/* Template Name: Login */
```

The url also includes a query string of where to send the user back to once they've logged in.
http://www.example.com/login/?return=%2Faccount

The link doesn't work - it sends the user to an entirely different page, with a 302 redirect.

However, a bare URL works:
http://www.example.com/login/

Strangely, so does an URL with "login" as a parameter:
http://www.example.com/login/?login=true&return=%2Faccount

The .htaccess file is the standard WordPress htaccess - there's nothing extra in there. I have the "Redirection" plugin set up, but it tells me it's not even being used in this case - the redirection happens before it gets to the plugin.

Does WordPress save redirects somewhere? So maybe it's cached? I've searched the admin for any caching, and don't see any. And why would having the query string make the link work?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance we can see the contents of that "page-login.php" file? I'm wondering if it will show where it's trying to redirect you to, and if you can customize it to redirect to include "login=true" as a parameter.

I would also check to see if your browser has any caching that is causing that 302 redirect, as well as disable plugins temporarily to see if that solves the issue.

Here are two articles that would be helpful in handling those suggestions:

- https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/fix-wordpress-login-redirect-loop
- https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-wordpress-login-page-refreshing-and-redirecting-issue/

Comment: I'll look those over, thanks. The page-login file isn't even being accessed - the redirect happens before it hits that file. I've tried clearing my browser cache, but that didn't make a difference.

Comment: What URL are you going to to log in? I'm presuming it's the `/login` URL that you mentioned in the article.

Are you able to tell which file is handling that URL/page/permalink?

Comment: That's sorta my question. It's supposed to go to page-login.php, but something somewhere is redirecting it, and I don't know what file in WordPress would handle that.

Comment: Have you tried deactivating plugins and retrying? A further test would involve switching to a basic WP theme like twentynineteen.  I'm also assuming you've read the [WordPress Codex on custom login forms](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form#Make_a_Custom_Login_Page).

If that doesn't help narrow things down, would you mind sharing the code that you are using in page-login.php?